# Can't Get Opaque Text Overlay to only Slide Right

Tags: html, css

I want to make my picture have an opaque overlay with text when I hover. I've managed to get it to do that but I want it to only slide right, and it's sliding right and up. How can I get it to only slide right? Thank you.

```css
html, body{
  margin:0em;
  padding:0em;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/dPJ5r9gl3kK6ijoeP1IRsvY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
#Bar{
  width:2500em;
  height:5em;
  background-color:black;
  text-align:right;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding:0;
}
#Logo{
  width:6%;
  height:auto;
  float:left;
  padding-left:11em;
  padding-bottom:0em;
  padding-top:1em;
}
#Menu{
  width:2500em;
  height:auto;
  background-color:#0e1f5a;
  text-align:center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding:0.5em;
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-family:Lato;
}


.DJHover { position: relative;opacity: 0.7; width: .4em; height: 1.3em;}
.DJHover .caption5 {opacity:0 ; position: absolute; height:1.3em; width: .4em;bottom: 0;left: 0;padding: 1.175em 0;-webkit-transition: 3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
 transition: 3s ease-in-out;}
 .DJHover:hover .caption5 { opacity: 0.7;width: 5.4em; height: 1.3em;font-size:5em;color: White; background: black; text-align: center; font-weight:bold;-moz-transform: translate(0em,0);-webkit-transform: translate(0em,0);
-o-transform: translate(0em,0);
-ms-transform: translate(0em,0);
transform: translate(0em,0);
;}


#Footer{
  width:2500em;
  height:5em;
  background-color:#0e1f5a;
  text-align:left;
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding:0.5em;
  font-size:1em;
  font-family:Lato;
  color:white;
  
}

#ContactButton{
  border:0.0625em solid white;
  background-color:black;
  padding-left:2.5em;
  padding-right:2.5em;
  
}
#Bar2{
  width:2500em;
  height:3em;
  background-color:black;
  text-align:right;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home </title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="file:///home/chronos/u-cba4e7cda58d8e8812f74a8c51a34fa154676b3f/Downloads/M1/StyleSheet3.css"/>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:black">
    <div id="Bar">
      <a href=""/></a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="Menu">
    <a style="margin-right:2em" href="file:///home/chronos/u-cba4e7cda58d8e8812f74a8c51a34fa154676b3f/Downloads/M1/Home.html"> Home </a>
    
    <a style="margin-right:2em" href="file:///home/chronos/u-cba4e7cda58d8e8812f74a8c51a34fa154676b3f/Downloads/M1/DJs.html">DJs</a>
   </div>
   <center>
      <br><br><br>
         <a class="DJHover" href="file:///home/chronos/u-cba4e7cda58d8e8812f74a8c51a34fa154676b3f/Downloads/M1/DJs.html">
           <img style="width:27em" src="http://www.dancefair.tv/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/How-to-secure-DJ-gig.jpg"/>
           <div class="caption5"><br>DJS</div>
         </a>
    </center>
    <br><br><br>
    <div id="Footer">
      <table style="padding-left:20%;padding-right:5%">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href=""><div id="ContactButton"><p>Contact</p></div></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href=""></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p style="margin-left:5em"><strong>TEL</strong></p>
            <p style="margin-left:5em"><strong>ADDRESS</strong></p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p style="margin-left:5em">&#169;2015 by <a href="" style="text-decoration:underline;color:Red"></a>.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
     
    </div>
    <div id="Bar2"></div>
      
       
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a working snippet by pressing Ctrl + M while [edit] question?

Comment: Click [edit]. Press Ctrl + M. Tell me what you see!

Comment: Okay I did it. The picture isn't showing up on here though.

Comment: Yes, because it is in your local.

Comment: So I'll replace the picture with a link

Comment: Can you see what it's doing now?

Comment: So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want it to only slide right. Right now, it is sliding right and up.

Comment: Are you able to replicate the issue in the snippet?

Comment: Yeah it's sliding up and right. I want it to only slide right. Right now it's doing this  /. I want it to do this |

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sliding up and right, your translucent overlay is actually expanding from `width: .4em;` to `width: 5.4em;` - this looks like the result of an unintentional typo(?)

There are other (also presumably unintentional?) typos in your styles

eg. `-webkit-transition: 3s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;`

I've reproduced below, what I think you're trying to achieve:

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

.DJHover, .DJHover img, .DJHover .caption5 {
display: inline-block;
top: 100px;
left: 200px;
width: 432px;
height: 264px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.DJHover {
position: relative;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
text-decoration: none;
opacity: 0.7;
}

.DJHover .caption5 {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
font-size: 5em;
font-weight:bold;
text-align: center;
opacity: 0;

-webkit-transform:translate(-100%,0);
-moz-transform:translate(-100%,0);
-o-transform:translate(-100%,0);
-ms-transform:translate(-100%,0);
transform:translate(-100%,0);

-webkit-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.DJHover:hover .caption5 {
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
opacity: 0.7;

-moz-transform: translate(0,0);
-webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
-o-transform: translate(0,0);
-ms-transform: translate(0,0);
transform: translate(0,0);
}
```

```html
<a class="DJHover">
<img src="http://www.dancefair.tv/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/How-to-secure-DJ-gig.jpg" />
<div class="caption5"><br />DJS</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Yes thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted it to do. Thank you

Comment: I notice that when I make the picture smaller, the text runs to the side, off screen. I don't want to see the text or opacity off the picture. I only want it to slide within the picture. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this with `.DJHover, .DJHover img, .DJHover .caption5 {overflow: hidden;}` - please see my amended post above.

Comment: Glad you like this solution, @TiffanyHall - if possible (or else when you have enough points) please can you accept this answer and / or upvote it. Thank you.

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry, I'm new to this site

Comment: Okay I figured it out. I have to get 15 points before it is displayed